# How to get anchor tag href and anchor tag text inside a div using Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

My HTML code consists of multiple `div`s. Inside each `div` is a list of anchor tags. I need to fetch the `href` values and text values of the anchor tags that are in the `sub-container` `div`. I'm using Selenium to get the HTML code of the webpage.

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div id="main-container">
        <a href="www.one.com">One</a>
        <a href="www.two.com">Two</a>
        <a href="www.three.com">Three</a>

        <div id="sub-container">
            <a href="www.abc.com">Abc</a>
            <a href="www.xyz.com">Xyz</a>
            <a href="www.pqr.com">Pqr</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Java code:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@href]"));
for (WebElement element : list) {
    String link = element.getAttribute("href");
    System.out.println(e.getTagName() + "=" + link);
}
```

Output:

```
a=www.one.com
a=www.two.com
a=www.three.com
a=www.abc.com
a=www.xyz.com
a=www.pqr.com
```

Output I need:

```
a=www.abc.com , Abc
a=www.xyz.com , Xyz
a=www.pqr.com , Pqr
```

Comment: `System.out.println(e.getTagName() + "=" + link + ", " + e.getText());`;

Comment: But i need to get only from sub-container div anchor tag values.

Comment: I added the xpath to select only the sub-container anchor tags to my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='sub-container']/*[@href]"));
        for (WebElement element : list) {
            String link = element.getAttribute("href");
            System.out.println(element.getTagName() + "=" + link +", "+ element.getText());
        }
```

Comment: But i need to get only from sub-container div anchor tag values.

Comment: @Karthik, Uptaded `Xpath`, try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.getText()` to get the link text.

If you only want to select the links in the sub-container, you can adjust your xPath:

```
//*[@id="sub-container"]/a
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, try as below:

```
 `List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='sub-container']/a"));
    for (WebElement element : list) {
        String link = element.getAttribute("href");
        String text = element.getText();
        System.out.println(e.getTagName() + "=" + link + ", " + text);
    }
```

Comment: But i need to get only from sub-container div anchor tag values.

Comment: edited my answer above, try changing the xpath in this case.

Answer (score 0):

if id sub-container is unique, just use the below line

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div#sub-container>a"));
```

thanks